# Working with dictionaries and data to and from database - Python 3

Tags: python, arrays, database

I have a data which looks like (as example) -

```
{"phone_number": "XXX1","phone_number_country": "XXX2","text": "XXX2"}
```

where XXX is my data (it can be different types of data)

Also, I have DB with data, which looks like (as example) - 
[[image: DB]

Data is taken from DB:

```
con = sqlite3.connect('dab')
cur = con.cursor()
c = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM some')
u_data = c.fetchall()
```

Each row is a set of data.

The data is taken from the first row and data from **column_1** goes to the place of **XXX1**, data from **column_2** goes to the place of **XXX2** and data from **column_3** goes to the place of **XXX3**...

After that I should get the data from the original array (template) + data taken from the database...then this dict should be committed to DB and the loop should go on until the data from the DB and every time commit my new dict to DB...

Now I have some code:

```
import sqlite3
from itertools import product

a = {"phone_number": "XXX","phone_number_country": "XXX","text": "XXX"}

con = sqlite3.connect('dab')
cur = con.cursor()
c = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM some')
u_data = c.fetchall()
s = list(u_data)
b = list(zip(*u_data))
out = product(*b)
tout =list(out)
i = 0
for elem in b:
  b[i] = elem
  a["phone_number"] = elem[0]
  a["phone_number_country"] = elem[1]
  a["text"] = elem[2]
  print(a)
```

and in console i have this:

```
{'text': 'phone_number31', 'phone_number_country': 'phone_number21', 'phone_number': 'phone_number11'}
{'text': 'phone_number_c32', 'phone_number_country': 'phone_number_c22', 'phone_number': 'phone_number_c12'}
{'text': 'text33', 'phone_number_country': 'text23', 'phone_number': 'text13'}
```

It should be:

```
{"phone_number": "phone_number11","phone_number_country": "phone_number_c12","text": "text13"}
{"phone_number": "phone_number21","phone_number_country": "phone_number_c22","text": "text23"}
{"phone_number": "phone_number31","phone_number_country": "phone_number_c32","text": "text33"}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: It's a dictionary, not an array ...

Comment: @MMF - ok, any ideas?

Comment: I deas for what? You haven't asked a real question. SO is not a tutoring service, google for a tutorial on updating a database using Python.

Comment: If you want help, you need to post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you have tried.

Comment: @CAB - yes, you are right... i've updated my question

Comment: What difference does it make what order you get?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham the difference is in how it adds the data and what data it adds... 
The order is not important...

Comment: I presume the keys match the columns?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Yes... 
Instead of taking 1 item from column and follow the row to the end, he simply inserts the values of the entire column...

Answer (score 0):

Dictionaries in python do not maintain the insertion order by default. You need ordered dictionary for this.

I have reproduced a part of your code below:

```
import collections
a = collections.OrderedDict()

for elem in b:
  b[i] = elem
  a["phone_number"] = elem[0]
  a["phone_number_country"] = elem[1]
  a["text"] = elem[2]
  print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer here:

```
a = {"phone_number": "XXX","phone_number_country": "XXX","text": "XXX"}

con = sqlite3.connect('dab')
cur = con.cursor()
c = cur.execute('SELECT * FROM some')
u_data = c.fetchall()
s = list(u_data)
i = 0
for elem in s:
    s[i] = elem
    a["phone_number"] = elem[0]
    a["phone_number_country"] = elem[1]
    a["text"] = elem[2]
```